# ModelAttribute in .jsp file: Can not resolve symbol. Spring

Tags: java, spring, modelattribute

I have primitive spring project for learning Spring framework. In my .jsp file I'm getting exception below:
[image]

But in my controller class I have `@ModelAttribute("student")`:

[image]

Bellow is my project structure:

[image]

In my `web.xml` file I have exception too:

[image]

Here is my Artifacts:
[image]

Will be glad to any help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception, provide more details.

Comment: My web page run and work correctly, but because of problem with resolving 'student' symbol, I cant write student.value (it works but without auto generations Ctrl+Space). And last argument: Although web page works, symbol 'student in .jsp' and 'dispatcher' shouldn't be red. All exceptions  you can see in first and last pictures. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same problem like me, you have to configure `dispatcher servlet` and mapping like in my `web.xml`. Resolving symbol error in web.xml means that in your pom.xml you shoul write: `<packaging>war</packaging>`. It works for me.

My pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringgMVC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

     <dependencies></dependencies>
```